# clear checked check box after clicking cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

html:

```
<div id="member_form" style="display:none">
    <form id="contactform"  method="post" action="." onsubmit="if($('input[name=name]').is(':checked')){return true;}else{$('#choose_warning').show();return false}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Choose Person</h2>
        <br />
        {% if contact_list %}
        {%for contact in contact_list%}
        <input type="radio" name="name" id="contact" value="{{contact.first_name}} {{contact.last_name}}" maxlength="30" />
        {{contact.first_name|title}} {{contact.last_name}}<br />
        {% endfor %}
         <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="" id="member_action_type" maxlength="30" />
        <p style="display:none;color:red" id="choose_warning">Please choose a contact.</p>
        <div style="width:180px;margin:20px 5px 0 10px" align="left">
            <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">
                <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/button-icon-ir-back.png" width="12" height="17" alt="" />
            Cancel</button>  {% include "buttons/add.html" %}
        </div></form>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".add_list").click(function(){
             '''''''
         $("#member_form").fadeIn(1000);
       });
      $(".close").click(function(){
         $("#member_form").fadeOut(500);
        });
    });
```

My problem is if i select a radio button and press cancel,if i open the popup without refreshing,the selected radio button is in checked mode,i want it to be clear,if i click cancel button and open the popup,how to do it here.

Comment: Post a jsFiddle link containing your codes.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. I realize it's the serverside code you've posted, but that's not really HTML.

Comment: @adeneo, this is Django and he has properly tagged this post as Django!

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo - It's still not HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it clears all radios:

```
$(".close").click(function(){
     $("input:radio").prop("checked", false);
     $("#member_form").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: ,it is working for 1st radio button in loop,other 1st it is not working(not clearing)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code for your query edit the name of button according to your use.And it will work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Check/Uncheck Radio Button</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".check-male").click(function(){
            $("#male").prop("checked", true);
        });
        $(".check-female").click(function(){
            $("#female").prop("checked", true);
        });
          $(".cancel").click(function(){
            $("#female").prop("checked", false);
              $("#male").prop("checked", false);
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male"> Male</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female"> Female</label>

         <button type="button" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> Click the cancel uncheck radio button.</p>  
    </body>
    </html>
```